# Error opening TIFF in python unknown pseudo-tag

Tags: python, tiff

I am trying to open a .TIFF image in python. My code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

photos = Image.open("haz(1,8grados).tif")
photos.show()
```

and I am getting the error

```
TIFFSetField: tempfile.tif: Unknown pseudo-tag 65538.
```

Can anyone help with this? I am running python 3 in Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the same issue. I get this warning, followed by a `Assertion failed: sp->libjpeg_session_active!=0, file tif_ojpeg.c, line 899`, which crashes Python. I am on Windows 10, using python 3.

Comment: I didn't manage to solve it. I ended up ignoring it and everything went smoothly. I don't think it is a big problem.

Comment: From what I have figured out, this is because of some deprecated compression method used while creating the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [confirmed bug in PIL / Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3413). It is otherwise an innocent warning, and nothing you need to do differently. You can't silence the warning, however, it is emitted from the TIFF decoding library that PIL depends on.

You can either download the Pillow source code and [apply the fix for the bug locally](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/3417/commits/2bf3ceee8515d38b94c28d3c5dd15226489adf5c), or wait for the new quarterly release that will be published in January 2019.